# App getting crash in consuming API using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, web-services, swift3

I am new in Swift Programming,I have consumed Api for my project when the data is availabe it working perfect, if the data is not available app getting crashes in JSONSerialization,the problem is in data?.count != 0 ,because data.count getting mostly 2 or some other number,If I try to change that line causing error.I don't know how to solve this ,can anyone suggest me.

```
func getData() {

    guard let URL = Foundation.URL(string:"http://xxxxx/xxx?xx=\(userid)") else {
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data,response,error in

        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Check your Internet Connection", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
                // your code with delay
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            return
        }

        print(data?.count)

        if data?.count != 0 {
            let received = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) //Here getting thread error
            print(received)
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: try `if data != nil` instead of `if data?.count != 0`

Comment: use `if let` or `guard let` instead of checking nil or count

Comment: if let or guard let ...what it means

Comment: it means if the data has value then it creates a property, i.e: `if let temp = data` means if data wasn't nil you have temp else skips the codes in if

Comment: ya....I understood thank you Tj3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this part.

```
if data?.count != 0
{
  let received = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) //Here getting thread error
        print(received)
}
```

So rewrite it using if let or guard.

```
guard let responseData = data else{
   return 
}
```

Now you can use responseData in JSONSerialization method. So the entire code snippet will look like

```
 guard let responseData = data else{
       return 
    }

 let received = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:.allowFragments)
     print(received)
```

In Swift if let and guard are used for unwrapping optionals. Using the "!" to unwrap an optional will cause a crash if the unwrapped value is nil. We use if let or guard to unwrap optionals safely. So as a thumb rule, you should only use "!" to unwrap optionals when you are 101% sure that it won't contain nil values.

Answer (score 0):

Use do catch block, e.g.:

```
do {
    let session = URLSession()            
    var request = try URLRequest(request: request)
            session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    completion(data)
                } else if let error = error {
                    completion(error)
                }
            }).resume()
        } catch let error {
   completion(error)
   }
```